# Not receiving value on react class components setstate callback

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I got this block of code using React Class Components .
After trying setState I receive on the Callback function -> activeOptions.length is still zero
though on the second time my code works just fine

```
doingSomething(){
        let bla= [{"name":"John Doe","age":25}]
        this.setState({
            selectedOptions: bla,
        },this.updateLabelText);
    }
     updateLabelText(){
        let some = this.state.selectedOptions.length;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the closure function

```
doingSomething = () => {
        let bla= [{"name":"John Doe","age":25}]
        this.setState({
            selectedOptions: bla,
        },this.updateLabelText);
    }
     updateLabelText = () => {
        let some = this.state.selectedOptions.length;
    }
```